# htaccess RewriteRule seems to be correct but not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all traffic going to any .php file to index.php.

For example:

domain.com/test.php

domain.com/test/test.php

.. should go to domain.com/index.php. Similarly:

www.domain.com/test.php

www.domain.com/test/test.php

.. should go to www.domain.com/index.php.

I have added the following rule:

RewriteRule (.*.com)(/.*)?/(.*.php) $1/index.php

which according to an online regex tester should give me the right result, but when I use it on the actual htaccess the rule seems to be ignored, and a 404 error is given instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The RewriteRule does not match against the host in its first parameter.  Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} arg=something
RewriteRule \.php$ /index.php? [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RewriteRule \.php$ /index.php? [R]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately it still doesn't work, it just brings up the 404 error instead of doing the redirection to index.php.

Comment: Any ideas why this is the case? Or if there are any other approach I should take?

Comment: Does your index.php file do any type of redirection or do you have other rules in your `.htaccess`? The rule should be working, do you have access to the main apache config to turn on the `RewriteLog`, otherwise have you confirmed that `mod_rewrite` is enabled?  Also, I added a condition to avoid a redirect loop that I forgot last night as well as a rule to check for querystring arguments on `index.php`.

Comment: Also, the trailing `?` on the rules removes querystrings, if you would them maintained through the redirect, simply remove the `?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# internally redirect all .php files to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/+index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ /index.php? [L,NC]

# remove all query string from /index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php? [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your advice, but again unfortunately it only comes back with a 404 error, instead of actually rewriting the url to go to index.php. Any ideas why this is the case? I also have a bunch of spambot blocks and IP blocks which are also not working. Could they be related?

Comment: It could very well be the case. I would suggest pls look into your access.log to see what you get why load this URL.

Comment: Also would you copy/paste the code again from my answer above. I made a minor edit.

Comment: Hi anubhava, thanks again for the suggestions. The page still returns 404 error. The reason of this mod is because our site was recently hacked and I'm trying to redirect 404 requests to the previous spam php file to the index.php. I also wanted to do e.g. /index.php?arg=something, to also return index.php, but I don't know how to do this. Very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, had to go to bed as it was very late. I just edited my answer above to **discard** all query string from /index.php as you asked for.